# Video Streaming using Python

Tags: python, video-streaming

Is there any library (or) application available in Python to support Video Streaming? It has to read the file and needs to stream over the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Flumotion](http://flumotion.net/)

It's a streaming media server implemented in Python.

Comment: It looks like flumotion is a *NIX solution.  Is there anything that will work on a Windows platform?

Comment: it only supports webm? why not support flash?