# How to setup a webcam server using Python?

Tags: python, video-streaming, webcam, httpserver

I have a Python application running on computer which uses my webcam, does some image processing, and provides some data.

Now, I want to make both the data and the video stream available via a server or website of some kind so that any computer or program on the local network can have access to both the data and the video stream (be able to access the data and view the video feed).

I know how to make the data available -- I can setup a HTTP server using something like Flask.

However, I'm not so sure about how to go about making the video stream available in a similar manner. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10578763/646543) question -- the OP has a nearly identical scenario to what I have -- but the answer was rather lacking in technical details. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336697/646543) answer which recommends something called "flumotion", but the comments state that it's a 'nix solution, and I'm working primarily with windows.

What would be the best method, or the best Python library, for making a video stream publicly available in the described manner?

Comment: Does it have to be integrated in your software and hence written in Python or you're saving your stream to disk or can redirect it to another software?

Comment: Either solution would work, so long as it works in real-time.

Answer (score 3):

I once made a DVR completely written in Python for controlling the V4L2 parameters of a video capture card and to implement the protocol to transmit the recorded files over a low-speed radio link. For streaming I tried both **VLC** and **ffserver**. In [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/441304/115413) you can find a lot of my tests with VLC, which might work for what you want to do.

Since I had to record the files to disk and also stream them to a local web interface (also written in Python using [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/)), I ended up using a `ffmpeg` process to encode the stream to **h264**, record it to disk and forward it to a [video loopback device](https://code.google.com/p/v4l2loopback/). Then, when the user accessed the video configuration screen on the web interface another `ffmpeg` process would be started to stream video from the loopback device to the video player using UDP:

`ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 -f h264 -preset ultrafast udp://hostip:port`

It is worth to note that, since this stream was a raw **h264** stream, the user had to have the VLC plugin to be able to view it, as most flash based video players are not capable of handling a raw *h264* stream.